# My IDE started to freezing after upgrade to kernel version 5.3.0-46

Tags: upgrade, kernel, java, 19.10, bug-reporting

I am using Jetbrains Rider IDE for development but after kernel upgrade (from v5.3.0-45 to v5.3.0.46) it started to freezing for a few seconds in my every action like scroll up and down or when I try to write some code.

Today I also tried the v5.0.3-51 but the result is still the same. Because of this issue I have to use kernel v5.3.0-45.

Only my IDE has this issue and the other applications work well. Here is a cpu history screenshot while my IDE was freezing.

[image]

I guess there is a problem between the JVM(Rider uses JVM) and the CPU.

*System Informations*

- OS: Ubuntu 19.10
- Memory: 15.3GiB
- Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz × 12
- Graphics: Intel® UHD Graphics 630 (Coffeelake 3x8 GT2)
- GNOME: 3.34.2
- OS type: 64-bit
- Disk: 512.1 GB

Also you can check extra informations about my system below;

[image]

**Note:** The problem started to appear after I upgraded my system on 12.04.2020 and 13.04.2020. Here is the upgrade history related to that time.

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which version?

Comment: @heynnema I am going to share informations that you need after 6 hours.

Comment: @Pilot6 I am using Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: Edit your question and also show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: @heynnema I have added a screenshot for you. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Lx0D.png)

Comment: Status please...

Comment: How is it that you're running kernel 5.0.3 on Ubuntu 19.10? Is that a typo?

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: If your question is correctly typed, it looks like you're running with an old 5.0.3 kernel on Ubuntu 19.10. Why? You should be running kernel 5.3.0.

---

Even though you have 16G RAM, I think that your 1G /swapfile is too small. Let's enlarge it...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 16G RAM and 4G swap
```

This line should already be in your /etc/fstab...

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

Then reboot the system to confirm proper operation.

Comment: Oh sorry about that. My kernel version is 5.3.0-51-generic. I have edited my question. I will try to expand my swap space and let you know about it. But during the freezing time ram is looking stable, only my CPU is going down. I got some software upgrade on 2020-04-12 and then this problem appeared. If swap expanding doesn't help I will share my package upgrade history.

Comment: Unfortunately, to expand the swap space is not helping the problem. I updated my question and added my upgrade history. I am suspecting upgrades that installed in 12 and 13 April.

Comment: @Goker  What version Jetbrains Rider IDE? Current is 2020.1.1 from April 28, 2020. Current JVM?

Comment: @Goker check for a software update and see if the -51 kernel is available to you yet. I seemed to have some problem with -46 that -51 seemed to fix. Did you upgrade your Jetbrains Rider IDE?

Comment: Yes I did, everything is up-to-date. I guess something broke in kernel version -46  and still continuing. Fortunately, I am able to use the IDE properly when I reboot my system with kernel version -45.